# how to make Div element editable and mandatory field in form

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required >
<div required style="-webkit-user-modify: read-write;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

In above code,div is editable and i want to make div mandatory and form submit should not fire if div is empty. Currently textbox is only mandatory field and i have no idea how to make div mandatory

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript for this, if I am sure.

Comment: i am ok with using javascript.

Comment: I have answered. Kindly check and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this can be done using JavaScript:

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp" id="frmMain">
  Username:
  <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <div id="requiredDiv" style="-webkit-user-modify: read-write;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
  var frmMain = document.getElementById("frmMain");
  frmMain.onsubmit = function() {
    var requiredDiv = document.getElementById("requiredDiv");
    if (requiredDiv.innerHTML.trim().length == 0) {
      alert("Please fill the div as well.");
      return false;
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Try this using JSBin or something, as the form is sandboxed.